# shell command to copy text appears to work but formats without returns in applescript to filemaker

Tags: shell, applescript, filemaker

I have an applescript to copy a batch of rtf files to a filemaker database which appears to work well but the text goes into the filemaker field without returns yet looks properly formatted, e.g. 
text starts as 
Fred Jones
1 The hill
London
and ends looking exactly the same, but when I use a filemaker search script on the text for returns it finds none
I need to have a conversion from rtf to txt otherwise there is a lot of extraneous formatting pasted into the field
I presume that there is something peculiar about the *** shell script line *** below, but I do not really understand shell script (and plenty of other things) - any help would be very welcome

the script is

```
set source_folder to "source" as alias
set output_folder to "output" as alias
tell application "Finder"
set theFiles to (files of entire contents of source_folder) as alias list
end tell
repeat with aFile in theFiles
    tell application "Finder"
        set fileName to name of aFile
        set fileExt to name extension of aFile
    end tell
    set outputPath to (output_folder as text) & text 1 thru -((count of fileExt) + 1) of fileName & "txt"
    ***do shell script "/usr/bin/textutil -convert txt -output " & quoted form of POSIX path of outputPath & space & quoted form of POSIX path of aFile
end repeat***
tell application "Finder"
    set theFiles to (files of entire contents of output_folder) as alias list
end tell
repeat with aFile in theFiles
    tell application "Finder"
        set theName to name of aFile
        set theText to (read aFile)
        set the clipboard to theText
        set theDialogText to "The Name of the file is " & theName & " " & (the clipboard)           
        tell application "FileMaker Pro Advanced"
            activate
            delay 1
            tell document "the filemaker database"
                go to layout "the required layout"
                create new record
                go to last record
                do script "Trial" --a filemaker script that simply pastes clipboard contents into a field
                end tell
            end tell
    end tell    
    end repeat
```

Comment: It looks like your shell script creates new files in the output folder. Why don't you open them and see if they contain any returns. That should reduce the area to look into considerably - esp. if the original files do contain some. -- **P.S.** Please make it easier for others to understand you: start your sentences with a capital letter and end them with a period followed by a space.

Comment: Would it be easier to use FileMaker text functions to remove the formatting after they are in FM? Check out the function: TextFormatRemove ( text )

Comment: @SoliantMike But how would they get there to begin with?

Comment: @michael.hor257k paste them in without using the shell script.

Comment: @SoliantMike You would have to open them in an application that renders RTF files for that. OP wants to batch process the RTF files.

Comment: Michael, correct all the output folder stuff is extraneous & apologies for text formatting.

Comment: SoliantMike, yes I would much prefer to parse the text using FM scripting, the problem is that the rtf ends up being pasted in with a very large amount of unwanted text which I would find it difficult to scrub; the function TextFormatRemove would be fine if it were only the bolding or italicising that I wished to remove but there's much other text that comes in.

Comment: Guys,  - unfortunately I cannot give you an example just now, but there are many % signs and numbers that surround every piece of text - bizarre that if I take a single rtf file and cmd+a, cmd+c then cmd+v into the fielmaker field, then it comes in just fine. But I would like to automate the process using applescript and if I do so without using the conversion to plain text from rtf then I get the large amount of extraneous material.       Thanks to you guys for your interest. Any ideas welcome :-)

Comment: You need to provide a way for us to reproduce the problem. I have tried this myself and it works perfectly fine - including returns.